# How can I give some CSS properties to a jQuery table?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm printing a table and I need to give it some border, font-size for example, how can I do it? thanks`

//calling my json function

```
 success: function(json) {
                    var html="";
                    html+="<table>";
                    html+="<tr>";
                    html+="<td>"+"Categoria";
                    html+="</td>";
                    html+="<td>"+"Numero";
                    html+="</td>";
                    html+="</tr>";
                    var meta=json.meta;
                    var nome=meta.categoria;
                    var risultati=json.risultati;
                    console.log("json",json);
                    console.log("meta", json.meta);
                    console.log("nome", json.meta.nome);
                    var categoria;
                    var n_poi;
// printing the array with the values
                    for(i=0; i<risultati.length; i++){
                        categoria=risultati[i].categoria;
                        n_poi=risultati[i].n_poi;
                        html+="<tr>";
                        html+="<td>"+categoria;
                        html+="</td>";
                        html+="<td>"+n_poi;
                        html+="</tr>";
                    }
                    html+="</table>";
                    $("#table").append(html);
                },`
```

Comment: Why not give the table html elements some classes and then have a predefined CSS block on the page that defines the style of those classes applied to the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to give the table an id or class and go on from there for the basic styling:

Change

```
html+="<table>";
```

to

```
html+="<table class='clName'>";
```

Then you could go further and give specific styles to specific cells, again using classes:

Change (for example)

```
html+="<td>"+"Categoria";
```

To

```
html+="<td class='specificClsName'>"+"Categoria";
```

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood the question. Can you not just add an inline style to the table like:

`html+="<table style='border:1px solid black; font-size: 20px;'>";`

Or add a class to the table like:

`html+="<table class="myTable" >"`;

and style it in css like:

`.myTable { border: 1px solid black; }`

Answer (score 0):

First option is inline css:
When you build your css you can add css like `<table style="border: 1px solid #000;"></table>`
or you can include a css on the page that contains styles like:`table{border:1px solid #000;}`
it all depends to what you prefer. Additionally you can also create your html with classes and ids`<table class="table-bordered"></table>` and create class styles on your css.